# How to compare two spark dataframes and get all the missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes:

Dataframe A:

```
column1 column2 column3
   a    25  ast
   b        phone
   c    32  dlp
   d    45  
   e    60  phq
```

Dataframe B:

```
column1 column2 column3
       a    25  ast
       b    15  phone
       c    32  dlp
       d    45  rare
       e    60  phq
```

I want to compare both the dataframes and write all the missing values to another dataframe, as Dataframe C:

```
      column1   column2 column3
           a        
           b    15  
           c        
           d             rare
           e
```

Missing values can be either in dataframe A or dataframe B, how can I achieve this using PySpark dataframes?

Comment: Should both `A` and `B` match in all column values (except empty values) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your dataset 1 is called `first` and dataset 2 is called `second`.

```scala
// we first have to rename the columns so we can distinguish which one belongs to which
first = first
  .withColumnRenamed("column2", "fir_column2")
  .withColumnRenamed("column3", "fir_column3")

second = second
  .withColumnRenamed("column2", "sec_column2")
  .withColumnRenamed("column3", "sec_column3")
```

Then we collect the columns:

```scala
val pairs = first
  // join the tables on the unique key, in our case, `column1`
  .join(second, Seq("column1"), "left")
  // collect the pairs to array, so we can check for nulls
  .withColumn("column2_pairs", array("fir_column2", "sec_column2"))
  .withColumn("column3_pairs", array("fir_column3", "sec_column3"))
  // we then select just the arrays, for the sake of explanation
  .select("column1", "column2_pairs", "column3_pairs")
```

The output so far:

```
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|column1|column2_pairs|column3_pairs |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|a      |[25, 25]     |[ast, ast]    |
|b      |[null, 15]   |[phone, phone]|
|c      |[32, 32]     |[dlp, dlp]    |
|d      |[45, 45]     |[null, rare]  |
|e      |[60, 60]     |[phq, phq]    |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
```

What we want to do now, is operate on columns `column2_pairs` and `column3_pairs`, if there is one null select the other value. This can be done with:

```scala
val newTable = pairs
  // in the collected array, if one of them is null, select the other value (for column2)
  .withColumn("missing_2", expr("filter(column2_pairs, x -> x is not null)"))
  .withColumn("missing_2_value", when(size(col("missing_2")).equalTo(1), col("missing_2").getItem(0)))

  // in the collected array, if one of them is null, select the other value (for column3)
  .withColumn("missing_3", expr("filter(column3_pairs, x -> x is not null)"))
  .withColumn("missing_3_value", when(size(col("missing_3")).equalTo(1), col("missing_3").getItem(0)))

  // do the final selection
  .select("column1", "missing_2_value", "missing_3_value")
  // renamings to get that to your desired format
  .withColumnRenamed("missing_2_value", "column2")
  .withColumnRenamed("missing_3_value", "column3")
```

Final output:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|a      |null   |null   |
|b      |15     |null   |
|c      |null   |null   |
|d      |null   |rare   |
|e      |null   |null   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with like this :

```
heywtu = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1','column2','column3'],index=np.zeros(5))
for i in first.columns:
    for j in range(first.shape[0]):
        if first[i][j] == '' :
            heywtu[i][j] = second[i][j]
heywtu['column1'] = first['column1'].values
print(heywtu.fillna(' '))
```

Output :

```
>>>     column1 column2 column3
>>> 0.0     a             
>>> 0.0     b      15       
>>> 0.0     c             
>>> 0.0     d             rare
>>> 0.0     e
```